# How to use character vector in formula in R

Tags: r

I have this formula for Rpackage `DESEeq` which takes `~Strain` as formula. 
I have `type.formula <- "Strain"` and want to replace the `Strain` in formula with `type.formula` and be able to run the code below. How can I do this?
So instead of this code below:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count.mat , colData = cond, design = ~Strain)
```

I want to run it like this:

```
dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count.mat , colData = cond, design = ~eval(type.formula))
```

Comment: Use `as.formula(paste("~", type.formula))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks!

Comment: @RuiBarradas Please post that as an answer, so taht MAPK can accept the answer and everyone can see, that the question has been answered.

Comment: @Bernhard If I post this as answer it will be flagged for its length. It's so simple I really don't feel like posting it as an answer.

Comment: Something like `type.formula <- as.name(type.formula); eval(bquote(DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData = count.mat , colData = cond, design = ~.(type.formula)))` is usually preferable because it shows the correct formula in the model output. Please provide a reproducible example.